# .P12 Certificate how to extract/create digital certificate

Tags: certificate, p12

looking for help or guidance on how to create a digital signature,
Extracting from a .p12 File
Each customer of ROS will have a digital certificate and private key stored in an industry standard PKCS#12 file.
In order to create a digital signature, the private key of the customer must be accessed. A password is
required to retrieve the private key from the P12 file. This password can be obtained by prompting the
user for their password. Thanks
can pay for consultancy service with our requirement.

Comment: This is exactly what we are being asked to do. This is public document, so hopfully ok to post. https://www.revenue.ie/en/online-services/support/software-developers/documents/aes/customs-excise-rest-web-service-integration-guide.pdf